# NEWRELIC Nreum wraps dynamic table content in script tag

Tags: asp.net, newrelic

I am having trouble understanding how the new relic works in specific scenarios, below is the scenario where the new relic is not performing as expected.

In my aspx ,  there is a button tag on click of the button a dynamic table is created which is shown as popup, but on incorporating newrelic into application, generated table content comes inside the NREUM script which does not allow the table to display as a popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"key","applicationID":"id","transactionName":"tname","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":701,"ttGuid":"ttGuid","agent":""}*<body>
<table  border="1" style="border-color: Maroon;">
<tr><td style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;'><table border="0">
<tr><td style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;' colspan='3'><b>Stack</b><font color='Blue'>1</font></td></tr><tr><th></th><th style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;text-align:left'>Overflow</th><th style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;text-align:left'>Step Description</th><tr><td style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;'><td style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;'><a href='dynamic_content.aspx'>Dynamic content</a></td><td style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:xx-small;'>Dynamic Content</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html></div></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></script>
```

But i was expecting the script tag to close before the body tag starts.

why the script wraps the content generated?? 
what should i be doing to resolve the same

Comment: This is JavaScript tracking snippet which lets newrelic to track the performance of pages for their customers using it. It provides performance data (and more) about your activity to new relic.

Comment: The JavaScript is supposed to be injected after </body> tag, but why it is wrapping my table content in script??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Relic Searches for the `head` tag and tries to inject the script in it. Make sure that your HTML has `head` tags in it.

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script></head>
```

Comment: we had missed <head> tag in the dynamically generated html, hoping main html page would handle the required scripts, but new relic did  search for <head> tag and inserted whole body into script , by adding <head></head> after </body> solved my issue. Thanks Akshay